# MYSQL installation issue in RHEL7.3

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat, rhel

While installing MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 getting below error. Please advise how to proceed further? Also, Installed client and devel.rpm files, though it got struck when installing server.

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.36-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Uninstall mariadb first.

Comment: I don't have MariaDB on the server.                                                           $ sudo yum remove mariadb mariadb-server
No Match for argument: mariadb
No Match for argument: mariadb-server
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Mariadb-libs then

Comment: How to remove MariaDB-libs? What is the command to find out MariaDB?

Comment: yum remove mariadb-libs

Comment: WOW..it's works. Great Raman!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, especially with constable jww from the stackoverflow police about

Comment: @RamanSailopal - The site is fairly clear about its goals and rules. Have you taken [the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand the site? If so, why do you object to the rules? The off-topic garbage appears to be growing at an exponential rate. When you answer off-topic questions, you encourage more off-topic garbage. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448).

Comment: If you think it's garbage close and remove the post like most sites do. If you want to enforce the rules, enforce them, there is no point adopting "soft tactics" that as you have noted, clearly don't work. I just want to help people as other have helped me. But unfortunately we are in a world of labels and political correctness where this should be said here and that should be said there.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me.

$yum shell

remove mariadb-libs

run